# How can I duplicate previous conditions in a if else statemente?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a calculator. Inside it, it is necessary to calculate the average of three variables, and now I am declaring an if else statement for when one of the three is equal to 0, it is to divide by 2. When two values ​​are equal to 0, it is to divide by 1. And case no value equals 0 divide normally. I'm programming in Wix using Velo. The message that appears is the following:

"This branch can never execute. Its condition is a duplicate or covered by previous conditions in the if-else-if chain. eslint(no-dupe-else-if)",

and if there are two numbers equal to zero, it continues dividing by 2, it is ignoring the second statement. Can someone help me? Here is my code:

I hope to be able to calculate the average with even if any value is 0.

```js
if (preço1 === 0 || preço2 === 0 || preço3 === 0) {
  médiaPreços = (preço1 + preço2 + preço3) / 2;
} else if (preço1 && preço2 || preço1 && preço2 || preço2 && preço3 === 0) {
  médiaPreços = preço1 + preço2 + preço3;
} else médiaPreços = (preço1 + preço2 + preço3) / 3;
```

Comment: Put the values into an array. Filter it by which values are 0. Count the result. Divide by that number. Don't have different if-else branches.

Comment: `if (preço1 && preço2 || preço1 && preço2 || preço2 && preço3 === 0)` does not make any sense.

Comment: Also, for future reference, `preço1 && preço2 || preço1 && preço2 || preço2 && preço3 === 0` looks like you are expecting `a || b || c === d` to check all 3 variables are equal to `d`, but it will actually check that `a` and `b` are truthy, and `c === d`

Comment: These preço1, preço2 and preço3 values ​​are inside a Wix database already, how can I do that?

Comment: Something like `const precos = wixData.query('preço').find().then(results => results.items), len = precos.length, sum = len > 0 ? 0 : precos.reduce((a,b) => a+b)/len;`

Comment: Also I recommend to not use diacritics in variable names. It is questionable if all IDEs and linters accept them

Comment: Why are you ignoring the 0 values when you want to calculate the average? Is 0 not a valid value?

Comment: Anyway, the solution is to simply count the number of non-zero values, then divide the total by that count.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to test all the combinations of conditions. Just count the number of non-zero values to find out what to divide the total by.

```
let countPreços = 0;
if (preço1 != 0) {
    countPreços++;
}
if (preço2 != 0) {
    countPreços++;
}
if (preço3 != 0) {
    countPreços++;
}

if (countPreços > 0) {
    médiaPreços = (preço1 + preço2 + preço3) / countPreços;
} else {
    médiaPreços = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
media = (preco1 + preco2 + preco3) / Math.max((preco1 > 0) + (preco2 > 0) + (preco3 > 0), 1)
```

- As @barmar said, this thing that you are asking is not an *average* count
- As @mplungjan said, it is not good practice to use diacritics in identifiers

Comment: Thank you so much bro, I'll remove all diacritics now